# Rockwell / sIFR 3 - with special characters (£, etc.)

Tags: sifr

Is there anywhere I can download a SWF fo sIFR 3 of the Rockwell font (like the one that comes with sIFR 3), but with a bunch of special characters embedded too?  Specifically the pound sign (£), but more would be great :)

I don't have access to Flash right now and I've tried the automatic tools but with little success.  I've looked everywhere, does anyone have any pointers?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the answer was simple.  A tool that does work with the latest sIFR revisions:

http://www.sifrgenerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a JavaScript only solution.

[Check this one out, it's called TypeFace](http://typeface.neocracy.org/). See also [here on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410608/)

Comment: TypeFace does look interesting, thanks for the tip - but I'm too far down the road with sIFR for this site.